# NSSortDescriptor NSDate ascending. How to sort objects with the same date?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nssortdescriptor

I am using an `NSFetchedResultsController` to display objects `Event` in a list. The `Event`-object has a property of `startDate` and an `eventType` property which is an enum of types `CheckIn`, `Concert`, `Meeting`, `Flight`, `CheckOut`. The `NSFetchedResultsController` has a `sortDescriptor` that orders the events by its `startDate`:

```
eventsRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "startDate", ascending: true)]
```

This works perfectly fine, however, in some cases the `startDate` for a `CheckIn` event and a `Meeting` event is exactly the same. This confuses the `sortDescriptor` and sometimes places the `Meeting` before the `CheckIn`.

Is it possible to make a custom `NSSortDescriptor` that checks if the `startDate` is exactly the same, then it checks the `eventType` property and returns `CheckIn` before `Meeting`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sortDescriptors` is an array, so add additional `NSSortDescriptor` for the second property you wish, something like that:

```
eventsRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "startDate", ascending: true), NSSortDescriptor(key: "eventType", ascending: true)]
```

This will firstly use `NSSortDescriptor` for the `startDate` and if they are the same will check value of `eventType`

Comment: Just to confirm: This is the correct answer (voted) and what I was going to say if Azat hadn't beaten me to it.

Comment: Excellent, makes sense. Thank you. But how will the eventType be sorted? How can I make sure CheckIn comes before Meeting and CheckOut after etc?

Comment: Enum is just a wrapper on integer constants. You give meaningful names to "magic numbers", so 0 becomes `CheckIn`, 1 - `Concert` and so on. Unless you give your own custom values to enum entries, they will have increasing order so `CheckIn` always will come before the `Meeting`